# Is my estimation a difference-in-difference estimate?

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, group-differences

I have a sample where a treatment is applied at a given time on all members of the sample - there is no control group, in the traditional sense.

However, the sample has two types of members, and my test hypothesis is that the effect of treatment is different on different the types of members.

To test this, I estimate:
Behavior = Time + Type + Time x Type

It is also hypothesised (and tested with Placebo) that difference in behaviour of different types is constant in absence of treatment.

The above estimation looks very similar to DID, with type taking the place of treatment group. But will this estimate be called a DID? If not, what is the name of this estimation? I have been trying different keywords (heterogenous treatment effects, intensity etc.) to find the accepted name for such estimation and similar papers, but in vain.

Any help on what should this model be called will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any observations on pre-treatment outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this situation is described exactly in [Shahn (2023)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.11030). The estimator is called "subgroup DiD" and relies on a simialr assumption to parallel trends, "subgroup parallel trends", which is that the counterfactual untreated outcomes in each subgroup of interest follow parallel trends pre- and post- intervention. The difference between the subgroup effects is identified even if the subgroup effects are not.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, this exactly describes the situation I’m working with!